# mongodb $elemMatch with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I want to query the following `Movie` object based on his `tags` array with `Mongodb`

```
Movie.last.tags
 => [{"type"=>"Genre", "tags"=>["Comedy"]}, {"type"=>"score", "tags" => ["Excellent"]}]
```

by using [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

```
Movie.where({'tags' => {'$elemMatch' => {'type' => "Genre", "tags" => "Comedy"}}})
```

I can query all entries with the `Comedy` tag, but I need to restrict the search to those that have in their `tags` array also `{"type"=>"score", "tags" => ["Excellent"]}`

Comment: Try [$all with $elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use-all-with-elemmatch)

Comment: @Veeram you are right. I posted the code below so that you could include it in your answer. I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You found the solution** [@Veeram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/veeram), please copy this answer and edit to your wish. I will accept it and I'll be thankful to you for sharing your expertise with us

```
Movie.where({'tags' => { '$all' => [
                        {'$elemMatch' => {'type' => "Genre", "tags" => "Comedy"}},
                        {'$elemMatch' => {'type' => "score", "tags" => "Excellent"}}
                        ]}
            })
```

Thanks a lot
Best Regards
Fabrizio

Comment: Its okay. Its just referring you to documentation and you did the hard work. You should accept your answer.

Comment: @Veeram I am grateful to have received help from **top 1% Mongodb** and **top 0.07%** expert on StackOverflow